# Package `varka' not found when installing Marlin of Fedora 17

Tags: fedora, nautilus

I'm trying to install the Marlin file browser.  I've already installed many required packages but I don't know what to do about this varka error.  Here is the output from cmake (the previous step) and make (the error-producing step).

```
[zzz@localhost build]$ cmake ..
-- checking for a minimum Vala version of 0.16.0
--   found Vala, version 0.16.1
-- checking for module 'unity>=4.0.0'
--   package 'unity>=4.0.0' not found
-- checking for a minimum Vala version of 0.11.3
--   found Vala, version 0.16.1
-- checking for a minimum Vala version of 0.16.0
--   found Vala, version 0.16.1
-- checking for a minimum Vala version of 0.16.0
--   found Vala, version 0.16.1
-- checking for a minimum Vala version of 0.12.0
--   found Vala, version 0.16.1
-- checking for a minimum Vala version of 0.16.0
--   found Vala, version 0.16.1
-- GSettings schemas will be installed locally.
-- GSettings shemas will be compiled.
-- GSettings schemas will be installed into /usr/local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
-- GSettings schemas will be installed into /usr/local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/eric/Downloads/marlin/build

[zzz@localhost build]$ make
[  1%] Generating LocationBar.c, BreadcrumbsElements.c, BreadcrumbsEntry.c, marlinwidgets.vapi, marlinwidgets.h, marlinwidgets_internal.h
error: Package `varka' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
make[2]: *** [libwidgets/LocationBar.c] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libwidgets/CMakeFiles/marlinwidgets.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you do a yum search varka?

Comment: Just tried yum search varka and didn't get anything. I also tried yum list *varka* and that came up empty too.

Comment: My cursory Google search indicates that Marlin and varka are Ubuntu-specific packages.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind compiling from source, you can get Varka from Launchpad. (If you have Bazaar installed, the easiest way to get the source is to type `bzr branch lp:varka`.)

To install (assuming that you have the required packages), navigate into the source directory, which should be named `varka`.

Then do

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

If you don't have the required dependencies, it will error, and tell you what dependencies you need.